# как индексировать столбец после data.columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Необходимо индексировать таблицу по столбцу "Campaing_id", однако после ренейма в "ID Компании" индексировать не удается.

[image]

```
data(index_col='ID компании')
```

Вызывает ошибку.

Comment: `data.set_index('ID компании')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего в вашем случае указать номер столбца, который должен стать индексом при чтении файла:

```
data = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0)
```

Если вам важно, чтобы индекс имел имя - можно сделать так:

```
data = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0).rename_axis("ID компании")
```

после этого вы можете переименовать столбцы, но только учтите, что `ID компании` указывать уже не нужно, т.к. это теперь индекс, а не один из столбцов.